# ASP.NET MVC 5 vs ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net

everyone!
I want to start learing and working in MS ASP.NET.
As I understood from the community's recommendation, I'd better to start with ASP.NET MVC 5, rather than with Web Forms. That's pretty clear.
Nevertheless, I haven't found the information about what it is preferable to get starting with ASP.NET MVC 5 or ASP.NET Core?
What do you think?
I would be gratefull for any suggestion or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to start from ASP.NET Core. At the heart of ASP.NET Core lies MVC pattern. So with ASP.NET Core you will de facto create MVC applications. Any way it is very similar with previous MVC versions like MVC 5 and 4. And yes , you are right about WebForms. It's good to get familiar with the technology somewhere down the road but not in the beginning.